# Corollary of the Skolem lemma in model theory

Tags: model-theory

In my model theory course it is stated that the following is a corollary of the Lowenheim-Skolem lemma:

> If $\mathcal M$ is a finite structure, then $\mathcal{M}\equiv\mathcal{N}$ implies $\mathcal{M}\simeq\mathcal{N}$.

But I don't see to what structure to apply the LS lemma since it require an infinite structure to work with.

Edit: I was asked for the statement of the lemma:

> 1. If $\mathcal{M}$ is a structure of cardinal at least $|\mathcal{L}|+\aleph_0$ then for all $\kappa$ smaller than the cardinal of $\mathcal M$, we can find an elementary substructure of that cardinal.
> 2. If $\mathcal M$ is an infinite structure, then for all $\kappa\geq|\mathcal{M}|+\aleph_0$, we can find an elementary supstructure of that cardinal.

Comment: Can you include the precise statement of the LS lemma you are referring to?

Comment: @MarkKamsma Yes I added the statement of the lemma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is true, but it is not a corollary of Löwenheim-Skolem. You need a complete different proof idea.

There is a connection to Löwenheim-Skolem: it demonstrates that the hypothesis of Löwenheim-Skolem that $\mathcal{M}$ is infinite is necessary. That is, your statement says that Löwenheim-Skolem fails in a very strong way for finite structures.

By the way, both halves of your statement of Löwenheim-Skolem are subtly wrong. In part 1, you need to assume $|\mathcal{L}|+\aleph_0\leq \kappa \leq |\mathcal{M}|$ (not just $\kappa \leq |\mathcal{M}|$). In part 2, you need to assume $\kappa\geq |\mathcal{M}|+|\mathcal{L}|+\aleph_0$ (not just $\kappa\geq |\mathcal{M}|+\aleph_0$).

Comment: This is a bit daunting as it comes directly from my course but thanks for the answer

Comment: I added one paragraph. Being charitable, it's possible that your course meant to say something like what's now the second paragraph of my answer, instead of saying it's a corollary...

Comment: That sounds plausible, thank you